# Regex match ordering 

Tags: regex, matching

My question is simple suppose I would like to match the vowels in a word, but I would like to match them in a specific order as the appear such as a, e, i, o, u. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So you're looking for `a` followed by some characters, then `e` followed by some characters, and so forth?

In other words, `a` followed by stuff that isn't `e`, then `e`. Then stuff that isn't `i` then `i`. Then stuff that isn't `o` then `o`. And finally stuff that isn't `u` and lastly a `u`.

In regexp terms, that's `a[^e]*e[^i]*i[^o]*o[^u]*u`

(You could get by with a `.*?` but why do that when you can more precisely define what you mean.)

Comment: You forgot some *s in there, but I think anyone would udnerstand.

Comment: a slight refinement would be:
a[^eiou]*e[^aiou]*i[^aeou]*o[^aeiu]u

Comment: So I did! Added the missing *s in.

Comment: @Alvin raises an excellent point. I have assumed that any string is valid as long as the vowels exist in that order. So uAuEuIuOuUu is valid, since I can spot (and have capitalized) an A-E-I-O-U sequence, despite an abundance of extra U's. If you need to allow vowels ONLY in that order, you would need to do as Alvin suggests.

Comment: @Votey your regular expressions doesn't match uAuEuluOuUu but it does match "sacrilegious' which proves your point.

Comment: With `/i` it will. (-: The caps were there for readability, rather than to actually distinguish them from lowercase letters. But quite right — "sacrilegious" would also match.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
a.*?e.*?i.*?o.*?u
```

But this has the same problem that is pointed out in a comment by Alvin to Votley's answer. This is due to the question not specified enough. It is not specified what the priority is.